# Align captions below images with subfloat

Tags: xetex, captions, includegraphics, subfig

The captions below subfloat figures are not aligned to the corresponding images. Is there any solution to that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]%
    \captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{{\label{fig_1}\includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a} }} %
    \quad
    \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{{\label{fig_2}\includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} }}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! I cant reproduce your problem (tested with recent MiKTeX).  Anyway, try the following figure code: `\begin{figure}[ht]%
    \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{fig_1}\includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a} } 
    \quad
    \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{fig_2}\includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} }
\caption{Figure a and b}
\end{figure}
`

Answer (score 0):

The environment `subfigure`  provided by the package `subcaption` does a better job.

You can set only the subtitles using `\captionsetup[sub]{<options>}` without the main figure's caption setting interfering.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption} % added <<<<<<<<<<<


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]  

\noindent   \begin{figure}[h]%  
    \captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
    \captionsetup[sub]{font={sf,it}}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Subcaption 1}  \label{fig_1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Subcaption 2}  \label{fig_2}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{\lipsum[4]}
\end{figure}


See figure \ref{fig_1}.
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```